# RxSwift cleaning a sequence

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a bit problem with a nature of Rx. As I understand correctly every value that is pushed to a sequence is holding and not released.
I'd like to ask if there is a way how to push this values from sequence away or release them.

Edit:

let progressSessionValue = PublishSubject() is called 10 times per second, which create a significant memory consumption. How to release the memory in this case?

```
selectedValue = Driver
        .merge(
            // you either use slider
            sliderChangedValue
                .withLatestFrom(progressTypePressed){ ($0, $1) }
                .map{ Double($0).stringUnitValue(from: $1) }
                .asDriver(),
            // or take value from the picker
            mainPickerValue
                .withLatestFrom(progressTypePressed){ ($0, $1) }
                .map{ Double($0.value).stringUnitValue(from: $1) }
                .asDriver(),
            // or use stored/calculated values
             progressSessionValue.asDriver()
                .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined)
                .map{ type, gen, segment in audio.retrieveValue(gen, type: type, segment: segment) }
        )
        .distinctUntilChanged()
```

edit2:

```
class BMMain_VM {
/// in
let didAppear = PublishSubject<Void>()
let didLoad = PublishSubject<Void>()
// pick up all generators
let genButtonPressed = PublishSubject<AudioGenerator.ItemEnum>()
let progressionType = PublishSubject<BM.ProgressionType>()
let selectedGeneratorType = PublishSubject<BM.GeneratorType>()

let manageSoundAction = PublishSubject<BMMain.SoundAction>()
//
let sessionType = PublishSubject<AudioGenerator.SessionType>()
//
let switchControlPanel = PublishSubject<Void>()
// slider changes
let sliderChangedValue = PublishSubject<Float>()
// picker changes
let pickerSelectedValues = PublishSubject<[Int]>()
// navigation
let infoButtonPressed = PublishSubject<Void>()
let toneButtonPressed = PublishSubject<Void>()
let menuButtonPressed = PublishSubject<Void>()
let navigateRoute = PublishSubject<BM.ProgressionType>()
//
let storeIsochronicType = PublishSubject<BM.IsoGeneratorType>()
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// out
// selected value to be presented
let selectedValue: Driver<String>
// values to be displayed in the main picker
let pickerValues: Driver<PickerViewAdapter.Element>
// select main picker
let selectPickerValue: Driver<[(row:Int, component:Int)]>
// select .static or .dynamic
let selectSessionType: Driver<Int>
// slider value
let selectSliderValue: Driver<Float>
// set slider dimensions
let sliderValues: Driver<ClosedRange<Float>>
//
let depthButtonHidden: Driver<Bool>
//
let manageButtonState: Driver<(AudioGenerator.ItemEnum, Bool)>
let manageTimerMaxLabel: Driver<String>
let manageTimerMinLabel: Driver<String>
let manageTimerProgress: Driver<Float>
//
let changeLayout: Driver<AudioGenerator.ItemEnum>
// let initAnimations: Driver<(BM.ProgressionType, Float)>
let updateButtonsState: Driver<Void>
//
let mainPressCombined: Driver<(BM.ProgressionType, AudioGenerator.ItemEnum, AudioGenerator.SessionType)>
//
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
init(context: BMMain.Context, audio: AudioGenerator, dataService: BMDBService) {
    
    let isRunning = audio.rx.isSessionPlaying.distinctUntilChanged()
    
    let sessionTimerValue = BehaviorRelay(value: dataService.getTimer())
    
    let progressTypePressed = progressionType.startWith(.amplitude).asDriver()
    let generatorPressed = genButtonPressed.startWith(.A).asDriver()
    let sessionTypeChange = sessionType.startWith(.static).asDriver()
    //
    mainPressCombined = Driver
        .combineLatest(progressTypePressed, generatorPressed, sessionTypeChange)
    
    // manage notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.rx
        .notification(NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "changeGenerator"))
        .filter{ $0.object is AudioGenerator.ItemEnum }
        .map{ $0.object as! AudioGenerator.ItemEnum }
        .bind(to: genButtonPressed)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    // set note value
    let updateProgressValueAction = NotificationCenter.default.rx
        .notification(NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateMain"))
    //
    changeLayout = generatorPressed.asDriver()
    //
    toneButtonPressed
        .withLatestFrom(generatorPressed)
        .bind(to: context.navigateNoteView)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    // auto switch
    toneButtonPressed
        .map{ _ in .frequency }
        .bind(to: progressionType)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    //
    infoButtonPressed
        .bind(to: context.navigateInfoView)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    menuButtonPressed
        .withLatestFrom(generatorPressed)
        .bind(to: context.navigateMenuView)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    navigateRoute
        .withLatestFrom(generatorPressed){ ($0, $1) }
        .bind { (arg) in let (route, gen) = arg
            switch route {
            case .binaural:
                context.navigateBinauralView.onNext(gen)
            case .frequency:
                context.navigateFrequencyView.onNext(gen)
            case .amplitude:
                context.navigateVolumeView.onNext(gen)
            case .depth:
                context.navigateDepthView.onNext(gen)
            }
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    //
    pickerValues = progressTypePressed.map{ $0.pickerTitles }
    sliderValues = progressTypePressed.map{ $0.interval }
    //
    sessionTypeChange
        .drive(onNext: { type in
            audio.reset(type)
            audio.manageGeneral(type) })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    //
    let mainPickerValue = pickerSelectedValues
        .withLatestFrom(progressTypePressed){ ($0, $1) }
        .map{ selection, type in type.consolidate(value: selection) }
    //
    let progressSessionValue = PublishSubject<Void>()
    //
    let changeValueAction = Driver
        .merge(updateProgressValueAction.map { _ in }.asDriver(),
               didLoad.map{ _ in }.asDriver(),
               progressSessionValue.map{ _ in }.asDriver(),
               generatorPressed.map{ _ in },
               progressTypePressed.map{ _ in },
               sessionTypeChange.map{ _ in }.asDriver(),
               switchControlPanel.map{ _ in }.asDriver()
        )
    //
    selectedValue = Driver
        .merge(
            // you either use slider
            sliderChangedValue
                .withLatestFrom(progressTypePressed){ ($0, $1) }
                .map{ Double($0).stringUnitValue(from: $1) }
                .asDriver(),
            // or take value from the picker
            mainPickerValue
                .withLatestFrom(progressTypePressed){ ($0, $1) }
                .map{ Double($0.value).stringUnitValue(from: $1) }
                .asDriver(),
            // or use stored/calculated values
            changeValueAction
                .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined)
                .map{ type, gen, segment in audio.retrieveValue(gen, type: type, segment: segment) }
        )
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debug()
    // two ways how to manage values
    Observable.merge(sliderChangedValue,
                     mainPickerValue.map{ $0.value })
        .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined){ ($0, $1) }
        .bind{ (arg) in let (value, type) = arg
            dataService.store(value, type: type.0, generator: type.1)
            audio.manage(value, gen: type.1, type: type.0) }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    // assign picker
    selectPickerValue = Driver
        .merge(
            changeValueAction
                .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined)
                .map{ (type, gen, session) in type
                    .select(value: audio.retrieve(gen, type: type, segment: session)) },
            mainPickerValue
                .map{ selection, value in selection }
                .unwrap()
                .asDriver()
        )
    // assign slider - do not know, why it needs to be twice when type pressed
    selectSliderValue = Driver
        .merge(
            changeValueAction.map{ _ in return () },
            progressTypePressed.map{ _ in return () }
        )
        .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined)
        .map{ (type, gen, session) in audio.retrieveValue(gen, type: type, segment: session) }
         //.debug("Slider value: ")
    // assign audio type
    selectSessionType = Driver
        .merge(updateProgressValueAction.map{ _ in return () }.asDriver(),
               generatorPressed.map{ _ in return () },
               sessionTypeChange.map{ _ in return () },
               context.showPurchaseAlert.map{ _ in return () }.as())
        .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined)
        .map{ _, gen, session in gen.getStoredType(session).rawValue }
        // .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debug("generator type: ")
    // update audio type
    selectedGeneratorType
        .withLatestFrom(sessionTypeChange){ ($0, $1) }
        //.filter{ isPurchased || $0.1 == .dynamic }
        .withLatestFrom(generatorPressed){ ($0, $1) }
        .bind{ type, gen in
            dataService.change(type.0, gen: gen)
            audio.manageAudioType(type.0, gen: gen) }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    //
    depthButtonHidden = Driver.merge(updateProgressValueAction.map{ _ in }.asDriver(),
                                     generatorPressed.map{ _ in },
                                     sessionTypeChange.map{ _ in },
                                     selectedGeneratorType.map{ _ in }.asDriver())
        .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined)
        .map{ $1.getStoredType($2) }.debug()
        .map{ type in type != .isochronic }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .asDriver()
    // autoswitch to amplitude when depth is not visible
    depthButtonHidden
        .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined){ ($0, $1) }
        .filter{ $0 && $1.0 == .depth }
        .map{ _ in  BM.ProgressionType.amplitude }
        .drive(progressionType)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    // audio
    storeIsochronicType
        .withLatestFrom(generatorPressed){ ($0, $1) }
        .map(audio.changeIsochronic)
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    // db
    storeIsochronicType
        .withLatestFrom(mainPressCombined){ ($0, $1) }
        .map{ ($0, $1.1, $1.2) }
        .map(dataService.updateIsochronic)
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Timers
    let sessionTimerStopAction = PublishSubject<BMMain.SoundAction>()
    // start session
    let progressTimerValue = isRunning
        .debug("isRunning")
        .flatMapLatest { isRunning  in
            isRunning
                ? Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(1), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                : .empty() }
        .enumerated()
        .flatMap { (arg) -> Observable<Int> in let ( _, int ) = arg
            return Observable.just(int + 1) }
        .debug("timer")
        .startWith(0)
        .share()
    // stop session
    progressTimerValue
        .withLatestFrom(sessionTimerValue){ ($0, $1) }
        .filter{ $0 == $1 }
        .map{ _ in .stop }
        .bind(to: sessionTimerStopAction)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    updateButtonsState = Observable.merge(sessionTimerStopAction.map{_ in },
                                          sessionType.map{_ in }).as()
    //
    let switchSegment = PublishSubject<Bool>()
    switchSegment.onNext(true)
    let timerAction = Observable.combineLatest(switchSegment, sessionType)
    //
    isRunning
        .withLatestFrom(timerAction){ ($0, $1) }
        .filter{ state, type in type.1 == .dynamic || type.0 }
        .flatMapLatest{ data -> Observable<Int> in
            if !data.0 && data.1.1 == .dynamic {
                audio.reset(.dynamic)
            }
            return data.0
                ? Observable<Int>.interval(.milliseconds(100), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                : .empty() }
        //.debug("Progressive timer: ")
        .map{ _ in audio.calculateFrequency() }
        .bind(to: progressSessionValue)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    // Progressive session recalculation timer
    isRunning
        .debug("Start recalculate")
        .withLatestFrom(timerAction){ ($0, $1) }
        .filter{ state, type in (type.1 == .dynamic || type.0) && state }
        .bind{ _ in audio.recalculateStep() }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    //
    isRunning
        .withLatestFrom(timerAction){ ($0, $1) }
        .filter{ state, type in type.1 == .dynamic || type.0 }
        .flatMapLatest { object in
            object.0
                ? Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(Timer.stageTime), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                : .empty() }
        .map{ _ in audio.recalculateStep() }.debug("Recalculate")
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    //
    sessionType
        .bind {
            sessionTimerStopAction.onNext(.stop)
            switchSegment.onNext($0 == .dynamic)
            dataService.updateType($0) }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    dataService.timerChanged()
        .bind(to: sessionTimerValue)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    //
    let setTimer = Observable.merge(sessionTimerValue.asObservable(), progressTimerValue)
    //
    manageTimerMinLabel = setTimer
        .map{ $0.timeString }
        .asDriver()
    
    manageTimerMaxLabel = setTimer
        .withLatestFrom(sessionTimerValue){ ($0, $1) }
        .map{ ($1 - Int($0)).timeString }
        .asDriver()
    //
    manageTimerProgress = setTimer
        .withLatestFrom(sessionTimerValue){ ($0, $1) }
        .map{ Float($0)/Float($1) }
        .asDriver()
    //
    manageButtonState = Driver
        .merge(Driver
            .combineLatest(manageSoundAction.asDriver(), generatorPressed)
            .map{ _ in .manage },
               sessionTimerStopAction.asDriver())
        .withLatestFrom(generatorPressed){ ($0, $1) }
        .map{ ($1, audio.buttonState($1)) }
    //
    Observable.merge(sessionTimerStopAction, manageSoundAction)
        .withLatestFrom(generatorPressed){ ($0, $1) }
        .bind{ reason, gen in
            switch reason {
            case .manage: audio.manageGenerators()
            case .switched: audio.switchGenerator(gen)
            case .stop: audio.stopAllGenerators()
            }
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

}

Comment: I`ll recommend you to read this book: https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/rxswift

Comment: it has all things which you need, this book explain how Rx does work.

Comment: @OleksandrVaker cool, I read some Rx books before, but there is probably no such thing like releasing sequence values.

Comment: if you read this book, than you realise how sequence does work. And what does it mean "releasing sequence values"? You mean "Side-effects"?

Comment: @OleksandrVaker typically Driver as shared Sequence is holding all values that flows through. All sequences do that, I believe to make time travel possible. If it is too many of values it has significant impact on memory. I wanna get rid of those values to release memory. I do not want to dispose subsribtions.

Comment: Ok, but what's the problem if when view dissmissed, you should dispose your driver? Dispose Bag will automatically release sequence from your memory

Comment: @OleksandrVaker sure it will, but I do not want that. I wanna keep my subscriptions. It is fairly a huge flows I am pushing 10 times per seconds from model to view and it can last for up to 9 hours. So after couple of hours the app memory consumption is several GB's. I guess I have found a black spot on Rx and maybe this technology is not suitable for a very complex apps at all. I just wanted confirmation.

Comment: @Vanya you said, "... typically Driver as shared Sequence is holding all values that flows through." This is wrong; they only hold the latest value, not all of them. You should read more about how Drivers work.

Comment: In your question, you say "let progressSessionValue = PublishSubject() is called 10 times per second". You do not show where that line of code is called. Maybe it's just a problem with terminology, did you mean that it emits a value 10 times per second?

Comment: @DanielT. it is PublishSubject<Void>(), which is not visible due SO formatting. The value is in this case getting from struct by functions "audio.retrieveValue". So yes it emits an action to get the value and request for action. Even the value is static like "8", it still consuming a lot of memory

Comment: @Vanya I'm sorry you are having a problem with memory consumption, but as far as I can tell, the problem is not in any of the code you presented, and the question you asked doesn't relate to the problem you are having in any way.

Answer (score 1):

An Observable, by default does not hold values. It holds a value producer function that is called every time something subscribes to it. The Observable itself never changes state, it simply emits the values as its producer creates them.

As such, there is no value to release and your question doesn't make too much sense. Maybe if you explained the actual problem you are having, we might be able to help you with it.

Comment: Sure, maybe I am mistaken. I have edited the question. So what is actually messing the memory? What is the object which holds the value to make time travel?

Comment: There is nothing in Rx that "holds the value to make time travel". If you are having a memory issue, then likely it is because you are strongly holding self in some closure (that's the most common error at least.)

Comment: Sorry @Daniel T. I have no vars and self inside my viewModel, just edited the question to see the whole viewModel, there is no self, no var

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it is not the Driver trait that is causing the memory problem, but Realm DB I use. The problem seems to be solved now and thanx again for pointing me other direction